# Git merge for conflict cases replaces local copy with the common ancestor copy

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

We are using the free self-hosted edition of Gitlab 13.8.4-ee. When performing merging in Git, if there are conflicts for a file that are not automatically resolved, the local and remote copies of the file open in an external tool (Beyond Compare) along with the common ancestor version.

If we are manually resolving one of the multiple conflicts within a file by choosing the server copy, and 'Save' the file in Beyond Compare, then for other conflicts in the file, the common ancestor version replaces the conflict lines in the local copy.

Is there a way to make Git replace the remaining unresolved lines within the file, with the existing local version itself?

Comment: *Git* is not doing any of the work here. *Everything* that happens here is done by the merge tool itself. So you need a way to make whatever merge tool(s) you use behave.

Comment: You can configure Beyond Compare to automerge all the things that are "obvious", but you need to handle *all* conflicts before saving and closing Beyond Compare. If you save and exit the file you essentially signal back to git that "here, this is correct contents for this file".

Answer (score 0):

We checked this is [not possible](https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/forum/beyond-compare-4-discussion/version-control-aa/86857-replace-unresolved-conflicts-with-local-rather-than-the-base-version) with merge tools like Beyond Compare or Meld, since it does not have a configuration to pick which default input for conflicts. Beyond compare also doesn't force the user into resolving all conflicts before a save.