# How to save merge state in Git?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge-conflict

We are using Gitlab free self-hosted 13.8.4-ee. During merge conflicts, we would like Git to save the state of unresolved conflicts in a merge as it is, so that we are able to continue resolving the conflicts at a later time.

We checked that in Gitlab UI's Merge tool, it is not possible. The 'Draft' option in 'Merge Requests' only makes the merge in a non-ready state, but we are unable to save resolved and unresolved conflicts, since *git mergetool* would resolve the unresolved conflicts with the version from BASE (common ancestor) rather than keep the local copy. We also checked that this is not possible in external merge tools like Beyond Compare or Meld. Even when checked in Github's free version, it is not allowing to save/close the merge until all conflict markers are removed.

Is there a way where we can save the current merge state in Git? In TFS, it is possible to save the current merge state as it is.

Please check the answer from previous question : [Git merge for conflict cases replaces local copy with the common ancestor copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999219/git-merge-for-conflict-cases-replaces-local-copy-with-the-common-ancestor-copy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

More precisely, the way you save *anything* permanently (or even for just a day or so, or for transport purposes, etc.) in Git is by making *commits*.  But when you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, you cannot make any new commits.  You want to save stuff so that the merge can be continued elsewhere.  So you're in a Catch-22 situation: you want to save the conflict, but to do that, you must first completely resolve the conflict, after which there's no conflict to save.

Git does need a facility for this, and there are several possible approaches for adding one, but—as far as I know at least—nobody has made it all the way through adding one.

(It's not a matter of whether files have *conflict markers* in them, though ideally the "preserve partial but conflicted merge" would preserve and then restore these conflict markers too.  The actual problem is that the index has nonzero staging numbers in it.  These nonzero staging numbers are what prevents writing out a tree, and without the ability to write trees, there's no way to save the various files.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  How do programmers manage this problem? Do they resolve the merge conflicts in a single sitting? If not, isn't resolving the conflicts with all the conflict markers in a single file very cumbersome/difficult with multiple changes?

Comment: You resolve all the conflicts in a single sitting. Ideally your workflow around git shouldn't produce *a lot* of conflicts. If you regularly come into a situation where you have plenty of conflicts you should take a look at that process as well. For instance, you may have busy files that everyone has to deal with, or your merges are merging many features. Disciplined developers would postpone drive-by refactoring and instead create separate jira issues (or whatnot) and deal with them on their own branch later instead of gathering big changesets. But perhaps you're just refactoring everything.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `git rerere`. Whether and how any web front-ends implement this I don't know, but from the command line it's very easy.

Here's the command-line version of getting into the situation you've described:

```
git checkout main
git merge feature    # has conflicts
resolve resolve
oops, cannot continue because reasons
```

and the question is, how do you suspend the merge and go do other stuff without losing the resolutions you've already done?

The simplest way is to have already done `git config rerere.enabled true` before the `git merge` (by e.g. including it in your standard template's config). Then the way to save your merge state is just

```
git rerere
```

which will notice and remember any new conflicts or resolutions; you can then `git merge --abort`. Since Git now remembers the resolutions you just recorded, when you rerun the merge, the same conflicts show up, git runs `git rerere` for you, and that sees the conflicts and applies your recorded resolutions from its rr-cache to the your work tree. You're back right where you left off.

```
   rerere.enabled
       Activate recording of resolved conflicts, so that identical
       conflict hunks can be resolved automatically, should they be
       encountered again. By default, git-rerere(1) is enabled if there is
       an rr-cache directory under the $GIT_DIR, e.g. if "rerere" was
       previously used in the repository.
```

---

If you're already there, if you're merging and have some added resolutions and and hadn't turned rerere on yet, it's pretty easy to do it retroactively.  For an inflight merge,

```
git config rerere.enabled true
git worktree add scratch @
git -C scratch merge feature
git worktree remove -f scratch
```

and now you can `git rerere` to record the resolutions you've already made.

Comment: Now if only there were a way to distribute the rerere cached data...

Comment: @jthill But _git rerere_ only remembers the conflict resolution done last time and automates the process, and in order to record a resolution for git rerere, the merge has to be resolved right? and secondly, the rerere cache would store only information for that  merge operation in progress so wouldn't this be a limitation ?

Comment: @ITresearcher it's a real cache, entries are reused whenever they're useful. Yes you have to do it yourself the first time, but when you do rerere after a subsequent merge it notices any conflicts that are the same as one you showed it the resolution for earlier and reuses those.

Comment: @torek you can just copy the cache locally, and you can almost trivially rebuild the cache from existing merges.

Comment: What I mean is: if you could `git push` the recorded resolutions, it would be possible to build a collaborative merge tool from this.

Comment: @torek easy enough to build, but seems to me just emailing your rr-cache or keeping it on like an sshfs'd mount would work pretty well and you can already do it.

Comment: in your last hint do I understand correctly that it is not a problem for rerere to register resolutions elsewhere than conflicts? we can record conflicts at `scratch` but resolutions at `head` and rely on cache? 
Also - is there any problem with manually running `git rerere` more often than necessary? or can i rely on the rerere's caching keys, for no duplication and no lost resolutions. For example I'm unsure if I should run `git rerere` before or after adding resolved files: no problem if I run it twice?

Comment: @zaabson no, that's talking about how to get rerere to record conflicts you've already resolved, by recreating them in a scratch work tree, so then you can manually `git rerere` to get it to record the resolutions to the conflicts you fixed.